# PHP: Count Duplicates and Remove Duplicate Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database of visitor IPs, and I'm trying to create an HTML table that shows how many of those IPs are from X country. I can get the script to show which country the visitor is from, but I cannot seem to find a way to show it in groups rather than line by line.

For example, currently I'm getting:

```
Country | Visitors
------------------
US      | Array
UK      | Array
UK      | Array
UK      | Array
US      | Array
MX      | Array
MX      | Array
```

What I want is:

```
Country | Visitors
------------------
US      | 2 Visitors
UK      | 3 Visitors
MX      | 2 Visitors
```

I've tried `array_count_values`, but it still lists every visitor by line and assigns a value of "Array" to every line.

The IPs are in a database and the script pulls the IPs and then assigns the IP a Country Code value based on the data in a separate file.

Here's what I hacked up with my amateur skills. If there's a better way to accomplish this, suggestions welcome!

```
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);


include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'connect.php'); 

/* Performing SQL query */
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM the_ips LIMIT 100")
 or die(mysql_error());

 echo "<table>";
 echo "<td><strong>Country</strong></td><td><strong>Visitors</strong></td></tr>";

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
     {
      $ip = $info['ip_address'];
      $country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip);
      $countrylist = array($country_code);
      $frequency = array_count_values($countrylist);

      echo "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>".$country_code."</td><td style='width: 100px;'>".$frequency."</td></tr>";
     }
 echo "</table>";
 geoip_close($gi);
```

Comment: why don'y tou try to group rows by country (if US and MX refer to countries) and then count rows?

Comment: You shouldn't use `echo "html-code";`, use this: `?> html code here <?php`, end the PHP tags and start them again when you finish outputting html. Use `<?= $variable ?>` to output a single variable

Comment: Yes mariosk89, US, MX are country codes. I'll try that. Thanks for the html tip too Pacha.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
     Count(Distinct country) As country_number
   , country
 FROM the_ips
 GROUP BY country
 LIMIT 100
```

try this for a start

Comment: Thanks. How would I do this exactly? I tried to replace what you have there in my code above and get "Unknown column 'Country' in 'field list'"

Comment: obviously, you'll change change "country" and "country_number" with your own variables. the code I posted is just an example using variables named after my own understanding of your problem

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for the exact method to remove duplicate entries, here it is. Assuming that your duplicates are in the 'name' column. Just change the 'name' and 'id' to your tables respective column names.

```
// Select duplicate entries
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name
                       FROM tble_name
                       GROUP BY name
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1");
// Loop through the results
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
// Delete each row by id
          mysql_query("DELETE FROM tble_name
          WHERE id = ".$rows['id']."");
}
```

**Note:** This will remove the selected results for good, be sure to backup your data before messing with any DELETE queries if you're uncertain.

I hope this helps :)